# Append data to a SQL - Should insert when unique record found else condition overwrite existing data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

The name of the table is not static. I have a list of records in a C# data-table. Motive to import rows to the MSSQL table.

Present scenario if any row fails or if it already has same data like(primary key duplicate detect) it does not process the append for the whole rows.

How to import data to table X with a list of success and failed rows

with conditions

1. when overwrite active, append all records including the duplicate records.
2. when overwrite inactive only append unique records and give list of failed records.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Have you used `MERGE` before?

Comment: I saw some examples for merge but all seem to suggest working on predetermined table structure and not dynamic by generating on the fly

Comment: You can build a string with whatever SQL you want in it, including MERGE. Just ensure you aren't open to SQL Injection.

Comment: "when overwrite active..."   I assume this 'overwrite' is a variable in your code? I suggest 2 different sql statements, one for overwriting and one for 'upserting'. You could then put those 2 statements in an SP with an IF, or keep them separate.

Comment: yes overwrite would be a variable/parameter if active then no matter matching data found or not, replace it with uploaded data. How would I pass datatable to stored procedure as parameter without the schema of Datatable create prior?